# Setting opacity/alpha with shapes/tiles in Google Android v2

Tags: android, google-maps, animation, opacity, tiles

I'm working on an app based on Google Maps Android v2.  Simply put I want to render some shapes or animations on the map.

Looking over the Android developer spec at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/package-summary

I see you can add Shapes, Polylines, and tiles.  None of them seem to have an opacity or alpha property I can set.

Ideally, I just want to set a circle on a marker (either by using the same LatLng) or as a property of the marker itself (overload Marker?) and have this circle be animated and partially transparent.

Ultimately I'm going to want some control over these objects and how they render.  Are tiles more appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All shapes (`Polyline`s, `Polygon`s and `Circle`s) accept ARGB as their fill and stroke colors. Just use translucent color like `0xAA00FFFF`.